# How to read JSON data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

Is this json data format?

`string json = {"answer":"Line 1","mark": 1},{"answer":"Line 3","mark": 1}`

I try below code but it only working with one param. ex: `{"answer":"Line 1","mark": 1}`. I try split json string but it isn't best way.

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json );

string asw = jObject["answer"].ToString();
int mark = (int)jObject["mark"];

txtAnswer.Text = asw + "////" + mark + "\n";
```

Comment: place your json inside array.

Comment: Your string `json`is not a valid string definition.

Comment: See http://json.org for JSON rules and/or search for online JSON validators to proove yourself if JSON is valid

Comment: @AIVN: The idea is not to manually *parse* a Json string yourself, but rather use an existing parser and convert it into an object of a given class.

Comment: put it in square brackets [ ], and it will be a valid json array

Comment: `{"myanswer": {"answer":"Line 3","mark": 1},{"answer":"Line 4","mark": 1}}` is json?

Comment: @AVIN all questions *"Is this JSON?"* can be answered by https://jsonlint.com/ - the answer is just a copy/paste/click away

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very basic JSON question which any number of tutorials could've answered for you.

Is it valid JSON ?  No, and [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com) could've told you that.

How do you read it in ?

First, wrap your JSON in square brackets so it's valid.

Then, define a `class` to store the records in:

```
public class Something
{
    public string answer { get; set; }
    public string mark { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, use JSON.Net to convert your string into a list of these records.

```
string json = "[{\"answer\":\"Line 1\",\"mark\": 1},{\"answer\":\"Line 3\",\"mark\": 1}]";

List<Something> records = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Something>>(json);         //  JSON.Net

foreach (Something record in records)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Answer: {0}, Mark: {1}", record.answer, record.mark));
}
```

Easy as that.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this json data format?
>
> ```
> string json = {"answer":"Line 1","mark": 1},{"answer":"Line 3","mark": 1}
> ```

Nope, what you've got there doesn't look like valid C# *or* JSON. Try putting it inside a JSON array, then inside a proper string:

```
 string json = "[{\"answer\":\"Line 1\",\"mark\": 1},{\"answer\":\"Line 3\",\"mark\": 1}]";
```

(Hope I've got all the escaping right there.)

That's the C# escaped equivalent of the following JSON:

```
[{"answer":"Line 1","mark": 1}, {"answer":"Line 3","mark": 1}]
```

Then read up on [`JObject.Parse()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm)for more info.

Comment: What happens when you pass the correctly formatted string into `JObject.Parse()`? The documentation for that that method should help. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm

Comment: @MikeChamberlain I would expect an exception

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is json format. But There are multiple objects. You are not looping through it. One way could be

```
dynamic dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
foreach (var item in dynJson)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}\n", item.answer, item.mark);
}
```

Comment: It is **not valid** JSON - it is just a lookalike - go to https://jsonlint.com/ and proove yourself

Comment: `Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create'`